# Evaluating $\int_c^\infty \sqrt{x} e^{-x/a} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How can we evaluate $\int_c^\infty \sqrt{x} e^{-x/a} dx$?

Wolfram alpha can't evaluate it for an arbitrary $a$, but if I set $a$ to be an integer, such as $a=3$, I [get](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20sqrt%28x%29%20e%5E%7B-%20x%2F3%7D%20from%20x%3Dc%20to%20infinity)
$$
\int_c^\infty \sqrt{x} e^{-x/a} dx= \frac{3}{2} \sqrt{3\pi} \text{erfc}(\sqrt{c}/\sqrt{3}) + 3 \sqrt{c} e^{-c/3}.
$$

So it seems the formula for arbitrary $a$ is
$$
\int_c^\infty \sqrt{x} e^{-x/a} dx= \frac{a}{2} \sqrt{a\pi} \text{erfc}(\sqrt{c}/\sqrt{a}) + a \sqrt{c} e^{-c/a},
$$
but how can we derive it without Wolfram alpha?

Comment: First, show that the derivative with respect to $c$ of both sides is the same. Then show that as $c\to +\infty$ both sides tend to $0$. Alternatively, you can integrate once by parts and then make a change of integration variables $x=a t^2$.

Comment: Maple will evaluate this for arbitrary $a$, provided I tell it that $a$ is positive.  Maybe Wolfram will, too?   https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sqrt%28x%29+e%5E%7B-+x%2Fa%7D+from+x%3Dc+to+infinity+assuming+a%3E0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By *'arbitrary $a$'*, I assume you add the constraints $a>0$ (otherwise the integral diverges) and $c\geq 0$. We start by using the transformation $u=\sqrt{x/a}$. The substitution leads to
$$\int_c^{\infty} \sqrt{x}e^{-x/a}~dx=2a\sqrt{a}\int_{\sqrt{c/a}}^{\infty} u^2 e^{-u^2}~du. \tag{1}$$
The resulting integral is dealt with using integration by parts
$$\begin{align} \int_{\sqrt{c/a}}^{\infty} u^2 e^{-u^2}~du&=\left[-u\cdot \frac{e^{-u^2}}{2}\right]_{\sqrt{c/a}}^{\infty}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{\sqrt{c/a}}^{\infty} e^{-u^2}~du\\&=\frac{\sqrt{c/a}\cdot e^{-c/a}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}\operatorname{erfc}\left(\sqrt{c/a}\right), \end{align}$$
where the complementary error function $\operatorname{erfc}$ is defined to be:
$$\operatorname{erfc}(x):= 1-\operatorname{erf}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_x^{\infty} e^{-t^2}~dt.$$
Applying $(1)$ gives your conjectured result.

Comment: The integration by parts is specifically letting $v=u, dw=ue^{-u^2}du.$